# Selecting and storing values, using those values in IN clause

Tags: mysql, variables

Is there a way to select a set of values from one table and then use those values in an IN clause?

I want to select IDs from one table and then update data for those IDs in another table.

So something like

`<some var> = SELECT id from tableA WHERE <something>;`

`INSERT INTO tableB <stuff> where id IN (<some var>);`

I release the variable syntax isn't real. just want to display my intent. I have read about SET a little but am still new to MySQL so it doesnt make perfect sense. Also it mentioned that SET could only set variables of certain types and they all seemed to simple.

Thanks!

Comment: You use `update` for updating values in columns.  You use `insert` for inserting new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id)
    SELECT id 
    FROM tableA
    WHERE <something>;
```

I'm not sure what `IN` has to do with this.

EDIT:

Oh, you want an `update`:

```
update tableb b join
       tablea a
       on b.id = a.id
    set b.col = ??
    where <conditions on a>;
```

You can also do this using `in`:

```
update tableb b
    set col = ??
    where b.id in (select a.id from tablea a where <conditions>);
```

The biggest difference is whether or not you want to use information from `tablea`.  If you do, then you need the `join` version.

Comment: actually I do need an INSERT but with an ON UPDATE clause. So I need to INSERT if it doesn't exist and UPDATE if it does. But I need to do so for all the IDs select from tableA